# Django displaying variables not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

in my template, i have:

```
 {{ output }}
 {% for event in latest_event_list %}
    <li><a href="/student/order/{{ event.id }}/">{{ event.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

in my views:

```
def order(request):
        latest_event_list = Events.objects.order_by('-date')[:5]
        #output = ', '.join([str(p.cost) for p in latest_event_list])
        output = {'latest_event_list': latest_event_list}
        print latest_event_list
        print output
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "POST"
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        print form
        else:
        form = OrderForm()  
    return render(request, 'student/orderform.html', {'output': output})
```

and in my models:

```
class EventOption(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Events)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.option_text)
# Create your models here.
```

In the website, {{output}} displays something, but the for loop shows nothing. Is there a reason to this? and how do i fix this?

THanks in advanace.

Comment: What does the `Events` model look like?

Answer (score 4):

You create `output` as dictionary itself. So you should call it like this:

```
{% for event in output.latest_event_list %}
    <li><a href="/student/order/{{ event.id }}/">{{ event.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```